# Raspberry Pi connection and process image data

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

Does anyone know how to connect the Raspberry Pi to the cloud server after acquiring the image, how to send the processed data back to the Raspberry Pi after the cloud server processes it?

Comment: Hey there you seem to be new here! You should consider providing what you have already tried! Also, what cloud server are you talking about?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.